# How to locate image link using selenium

Tags: selenium

Unable to locate image hyperlink on my profile.

Tried using `xpath`, `css locator` but nothing worked.

1. `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("//img[contains(@src,'https://d3ejdag3om7lbm.cloudfront.net/assets/img/Default User.png')]")).click();`
2. `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='user_name']")).click();`
3. `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[class='user_name']")).click();`

Selenium fails to find the element.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOo1t.png)

Comment: check if there is any iframe before your element.

Comment: @Sanjay Ramesh can you share the url link ?

Comment: @Sureshmani---i had a look but its not a frame.

Comment: @Frian---The URL is https://learning.edureka.co/ ...for testing purpose i have created UN and Pw. UN- selenium.test1908@gmail.com
Pw- Selenium@1234

Answer (score 0):

try the below one if it not inside the frame driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'https://d3ejdag3om7lbm.cloudfront.net/assets/img/Default')]/parent::button"))

if the above one is not working try using javascript executer and click

Comment: Hi Nirmal, as you suggested about javascriptExecutor..JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element); the question is what should i fill in for the element part, since its an image which i'm trying to locate.

Answer (score 0):

In our application I had the exact same issue. I was trying to click the user image from a dropdown and I know my selectors were all correct. It would click occasionally but never consistently. Even fiddling with wait times didn't bring results.

Your selectors look good. You can also try By.xpath("//img[@class='user_image']. As css selector it would be img[class='user_image'].

As for @NirmalKumar's suggestion you can try his xpath and javascriptexecutor. You can also try clicking with Actions class.

My solution: I ended up adding an id for the web element through the javascript code. Are you able to ask one of the frontend devs to add an id for that particular element?

Comment: Hi David- Its a learning site and asking devs for adding id is far from my reach.

Answer (score 0):

as per your question,you want to click on image icon,try below xpath it will definitely works irrespective of any user logins.Please let me know whether it is working or not and i've login with your dummy credentials and in html elements btn-group open class is not displaying.

```
//div[@class='btn-group']/button/img[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your selectors

[image]

It might be the case you just need to add an [Explicit Wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) to ensure that the element, you're trying to interact with is present and clickable like:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,10)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='user_name']")))
        .click();
```

More information:

- [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html)
- [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)
- [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)

Comment: new WebDriverWait(driver,20)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='webinar-profile-name']")))
        .click();